# Please suggest some solutions for building a download service

Tags: java, database, http, web-services, download

I'm planning a web service providing file download service for handheld devices.

The requirement I have is use HTTP or FTP Protocol to build a server, use database, store files and provide Command Line Interface for devices to download requested files. No platforms and languages limit.

I'm a student and I'm learning Java Web(practicing Structs2, haven't started learnning Spring or Hibernate), and this is just a simulate project which may be required in a E-Book company. So I'm feeling like to use Java to build the service.

I'm now doing the requirement analysis, please give me some suggestions. About how to design the structure, book files stored in database or filesystem, any open source library to refer to... About any aspect is OK.

I just want to know what can I do to make it better and where I should be paying attention to.

Comment: This is far too vague. It sounds like you need to setup Apache and point it at a bunch of static content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a simple Servlet, which returns files based on request arguments.

Then, use your command line client to call the Servlet with the correct parameters, depending on what the user typed.

EDIT: more info on Java Servlet technology [here](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/). If you are learning Struts, you could implement your servlet there, but it might be a bit of overkill.